# How to create XSD document from an XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT, now i need to create a new XSD document from that xslt.

Please any one help.

Comment: What is that XSD supposed to represent? The elements transformed by the XSLT?, or perhaps the output?

Comment: XSLT is about transforming an input with well known schema to an output with well known schema.

Comment: I mean XSD Schema not the XML. If we give the XML to XSLT it will transform and give another XML. But i need to create XSD Schema.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you already have this flow

```
input XML --> XSLT --> output XML
```

Now its not clear if you want to creat the XSD for the input or output xml.
There are many tools which will help you in generating XSD schema from a given XML.

Here is one of those you can try online: [click here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)
You can of course google for more or if you want to download a desktop version.